# With the merchant api, can I create specials, campaigns, tips, venue information?

Tags: foursquare

With the merchant api, can I create specials, campaigns, tips, venue information or only is for get information? I only view the get functions...

Comment: sorry not view the add command at the left...

Answer (score 1):

You can see the list of endpoints @ https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/index, which includes endpoints like [/specials/add](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/specials/add) for creating new specials.